# What's a good way to clean up my migrations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

So I've been working on this web app for a year now and I would like to compile to schema into ONE migration, that way my text editor loads faster, git working directory isn't so cluttered.

Search find will be faster.

Any my config/db won't be 4000px long.

Comment: I think this also raises a suggestion for improvement of migrations in Rails. Really, who does rake db:rollback STEP=10?! Why do we need to keep our migrations in our project since we have a working schema? Perhaps there's a rake db:clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go is to take a blank database and run all the migrations. Now you've got all the template data which you can save to a yaml. The yaml plus the schema should be enough to bring the DB back without running any of your previously existing migrations.

However, other answers should mention an existing tool or gem for doing this.

Comment: Was hoping for more specific commands or gems like you mentioned :-)

Comment: Yes, just copy-paste **db/schema.rb** content into the new migration, it's enough

Answer (score 12):

Remove the migration files once you've migrated your servers. If you ever want to start with a fresh deployment, run `rake db:schema:load` or `rake db:setup`. You shouldn't be re-running all your migrations as explained [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark).

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to keep your migrations around forever, you are free to delete them as soon as you're sure you don't need them anymore. Just go into your `db/migrate/` directory and delete the migrations that are older than, say, a couple months.

As long as all the migrations that you want to delete have been applied everywhere (i.e. development and production) then you don't need them anymore (unless you want to go backwards). Really, migrations aren't meant to be permanent files, they're just around to get you from A to B and then they're just baggage.

Answer (score 3):

Given that none of the answers mention it, this is the gem that does the job: https://github.com/jalkoby/squasher

It basically reruns the migrations from scratch until the date you specify, and then loads the resulting `db/schema.rb` into an initial migration that replaces the old ones. It can also cleanup the `schema_migrations` table so you don't get those

```
up     <timestamp>  ********** NO FILE **********
```

entries when running `rake db:migrate:status`.